# Missing routes in rails after using resource keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Not sure what the issue is here, but I have a basic line in my routes.rb:

```
resource :videos
```

But I don't see all the paths.  Namely:

```
GET /videos/:id
```

I only see the following when running "rake routes":

```
videos      POST   /videos(.:format)              videos#create
new_videos  GET    /videos/new(.:format)          videos#new
edit_videos GET    /videos/edit(.:format)         videos#edit
            GET    /videos(.:format)              videos#show
            PUT    /videos(.:format)              videos#update
            DELETE /videos(.:format)              videos#destroy
```

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You make videos a singular resource, but videos is a collection so you have to do :

```
resources :videos
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Answer (score 4):

Change your line to `resources :videos`, and the missing route will magically appear

Comment: Ahh, I see. It's in the rails docs -- it's just really easy to glance over that extra "s".  Thanks!